# Как узнать все слушатели для определенного экшена?

Tags: php, symfony

**Есть ли какой-либо способ узнать какие слушатели используются для опредленного роута или куска кода?**

Т.е. есть метод контроллера, написанный не мной, т.е. я не знаю как что и как где подключено, надо это узнать. На ивенты, которые в нем используются (как самописные, так и в скаченных либах) навешано куча слушателей, которые выполняются в ходе экшена. Все названия ивентов не известны, так как используются либы из папки вендор. Не лазить же в них с целью поиска названий ивентов. 
Через `debug:event-dispatcher`  вроде как не вариант, так как там просто список ивентов и слушателей для них.

Как, грубо говоря, увидеть всю картину выплняемого кода?

Comment: в дебаг панели должен быть весь стек вызовов - что и в каком порядке дёргалось.

Comment: @n.osennij спасибо!